# React - Passing props to 'ES6 extends' components, and the correct use of 'bind'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a simple Inbox, that makes an api call and returns json object containing a list of messages. This is then passed via props down to the 'InboxList' and then 'InboxItem' components.  However, I am struggling to get props down to render each item.

I am also receiving an error when using bind(this), which is the following.

```
index.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (intermediate value).bind is not a function(…)
```

I believe i need to bind within my componentDidMount method due to es6 syntax, but I do not understand what the error refers to.  Fwiw the json data is coming back successfully.

Any leads on this would be most appreciated

```
export default class Inbox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.serverRequest = axios.get('/api/messages')
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(res => {
        if (res instanceof Error) {
          console.log(res.message);
        } else {
          console.log(res.data);
        }
        this.setState({
          messages: res.data,
        }.bind(this));
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InboxHeader />
        <InboxList messages={this.state.messages} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class InboxList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="dm-inbox__list">
        {this.props.messages.map(message =>
          <InboxItem message={message} />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The correct answer is below, but just as a pinpoint, your are getting the `bind is not a function`, because you are binding the object, and not the function, so this.setState({...}).bind, will not throw the above error, but this is not the true answer, but just to explain that specific error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this for more info http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/
A fix for you below. no need to bind to the promise
https://www.toptal.com/javascript/10-most-common-javascript-mistakes

```js
xport default class Inbox extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      messages: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    //serverRequest remove it 
    //this.serverRequest = axios.get('/api/messages')
     
        axios.get('/api/messages')
        .then((response)=>{
          console.log(response);
          if(response.status===200){
            return response.data;
          } else {
            throw new Error("Server response wasn't ok");
          }

        })
        .then((responseData)=>{
          this.setState({messages:responseData});
        }).catch((error)=>{
          
        });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <InboxHeader />
      //the messages array might be still empty cause the network call is async so do a check in the inbox list
        <InboxList messages={this.state.messages} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class InboxList extends Component {
  render() {
    //check if null or empty if not yet resolved show loading eg spinner 
    if(!this.props.messages){
       return <div>loading....</div>;
     }
    return (
      <ul className="dm-inbox__list">
        {this.props.messages.map(message =>
          <InboxItem message={message} />
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export const fetchResource = msg => WrappedComponent =>
  class extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        resource: null,
        msg: null
      };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({msg})
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/miketembos/repos')
        .then((response)=>{
          console.log(response);
          if(response.status===200){
            return response.data;
          } else {
            throw new Error("Server response wasn't ok");
          }

        })
        .then((responseData)=>{
          this.setState({resource:responseData});
        }).catch((error)=>{
          this.props.history.pushState(null, '/error');
        });
    }

    render(){
      const {resource} = this.state
      return <Posts {...this.props} {...resources } />
    }
  }
```